# Drop down list values linking with mySQL values issue

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu

I have drop down lists to convert one currency to another after a user enters a value into a text box, selects the currency symbols (USD->AUD for example) and then clicks convert and the currency converted should be output onto the page.

This is the php code that grabs the data from the database from the tables currency and rate and assigns to the options value to be used in the drop down lists.

```
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($refDB)) { 

$currency=$row["currency"];
$rate=$row["rate"];     

$options.="<option/$rate/>".$currency;
}
```

Here are the drop down lists that populate the data. So far the symbols are being populated but I am unsure if I am passing the rates properly through the drop down lists as those are the values I am using.

```
<select id = "convert1" width="10"> 
<option value=0>From 
<?=$options?> 
</select> 

<select id = "convert2" width="10">  
<option value=0>To 
<?=$options?> 
</select>
```

After the user selects the "Convert Currency Button":

```
                <input type="button" name="convertCurrency" value="Convert Currency" onClick="entry.value=convert(entry);">
```

This is where the user enters the value they want to convert:

```
<input type="text" id="enter" name="entry" size="18" value = "0">
```

It is taken to the JavaScript to convert the currency:

```
function convert(entry)
{



var convert1 = document.getElementById("convert1");
convert1.options[convert1.selectedIndex].value;

var convert2 = document.getElementById("convert2");
convert2.options[convert2.selectedIndex].value;


var sum = (entry/convert1)*(convert2);

return sum;

}
```

Though what it is returning is "NaN" suggesting it is "Not a number", so therefore I must be putting the rate value through the drop down list incorrectly I assume.

```
$options.="<option/$rate/>".$currency;
```

I think I am doing something wrong with the above code. I have tried assigning the rate preferably as a hidden value next to the currency symbol to no avail. If anyone could show me in the right direction to properly connecting mySQL column values through drop down lists correctly that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed, my javascript just was not properly assigned.

```
function convert(entry)
{   
    var e1 = entry.value;

    var convert1 = document.getElementById("convert1");
    var v1 = convert1.options[convert1.selectedIndex].value;

    var convert2 = document.getElementById("convert2");
    var v2 = convert2.options[convert2.selectedIndex].value;

    var sum = ((e1/parseFloat(v1))*parseFloat(v2));

    return sum;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the value attribute

```
$options.="<option value='$rate'>".$currency;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong with your JavaScript code:

You get the element with the id "convert1" and assign it to variable convert1. On the next line you retrieve the value of the selected option but you don't assign it to a variable. So when calculating the sum you are actually operation on DOM elements instead of numbers.

```
var convert1 = document.getElementById("convert1");
convert1.options[convert1.selectedIndex].value;

var convert2 = document.getElementById("convert2");
convert2.options[convert2.selectedIndex].value;

// Divides entry of type ? with DOM element and multiplies with DOM element
var sum = (entry/convert1)*(convert2);
```

You have to make sure you work on the right objects, add some validation for null references and convert the value to an integer before calculation sums.

Comment: Sorry, I have added the entry code to the question. It is just the value the user enters, right now I just have it set to update the same box with the converted value. I have tried parseInt but I still get "NaN"

Comment: Aren't these two convert values supposed to be currencies? Why do you want them to be parsed as integer? You have to convert the value from your text box and then do the conversion.

Comment: Oh sorry, yes of course, passed them through as a float and the entry as well. It is still resulting in the "NaN" error

Comment: all good, I worked it out, I will post up the answer for others soon, just a simple error with javascript variables

Comment: Thanks for your help ZombieHunter!